# CodeIgniter 3.0.0 where_not_in produces `NOT` for one column only in query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I'm updating my current CodeIgniter site from version 2.1.4 to 3.0.0 and I'm following the documentation listed on [CodeIgniter's site](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html) where I updated my database driver from `mysql` to `mysqli`. I came to a point where my site ran a MySQL syntax error for my MySQL database whenever I try to exclude certain products and specific brands...

```
$this->db->where_not_in('product_tbl.productID', $voidProducts);
$this->db->where_not_in('product_tbl.brand', $voidBrands);
```

This seems to produce extra backticks ( ` ) around the NOT argument in the resulting query as you see below...

```
SELECT * FROM `product_tbl` WHERE collection IS NOT NULL AND `product_tbl`.`productID` NOT IN('1', '2', '3', '4') AND product_tbl.brand `NOT` IN('brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3') GROUP BY `collection` ORDER BY `collection` ASC
```

If I try to run the SQL query directly on the MySQL database it works fine as long as I take the backticks out from the NOT associated to the products_tbl.brand column.

I have the same where_not_in function to filter out any specific products this shop may not want to display specifically and that works fine. This problem only seems to happen on the on brand column. I tried putting them in a different order and the brand column still produces the same error while the productID column does not. I tried commenting the brand where_not_in statement out and it works until it breaks on another model when it gets to searching through brands again, where it runs the same error on the brand column but not on any other column I might be separating things out on with where_not_in.

I'm not sure what to even fully include in this question which would be diagnostically helpful but please let me know what else I should include to help troubleshoot this problem. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

TLDR: where_not_in(); produces extra backticks on NOT for specific column in CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: Try with `FALSE` as third parameter. Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 3.0.1 seems to get rid of this and other problems
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62548.html

Answer (score 0):

Update to 3.0.1 should fix this (as stated by @JuanitoMint)

However, if for some reason, you cannot update to 3.0.1 (It is still on RC2 as I write this answer), you can do this workaround:

Modify `system/database/DB_query_builder.php`, at line 2355 (function `_compile_wh`), add this:

```
// temporal fix (has already been fixed in 3.0.1)
if($matches[2] == 'NOT'){
    continue;
}
```

This is how the whole function will looks like:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Compile WHERE, HAVING statements
     *
     * Escapes identifiers in WHERE and HAVING statements at execution time.
     *
     * Required so that aliases are tracked properly, regardless of wether
     * where(), or_where(), having(), or_having are called prior to from(),
     * join() and dbprefix is added only if needed.
     *
     * @param   string  $qb_key 'qb_where' or 'qb_having'
     * @return  string  SQL statement
     */
    protected function _compile_wh($qb_key)
    {
        if (count($this->$qb_key) > 0)
        {
            for ($i = 0, $c = count($this->$qb_key); $i < $c; $i++)
            {
                // Is this condition already compiled?
                if (is_string($this->{$qb_key}[$i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                elseif ($this->{$qb_key}[$i]['escape'] === FALSE)
                {
                    $this->{$qb_key}[$i] = $this->{$qb_key}[$i]['condition'];
                    continue;
                }

                // Split multiple conditions
                $conditions = preg_split(
                    '/(\s*AND\s+|\s*OR\s+)/i',
                    $this->{$qb_key}[$i]['condition'],
                    -1,
                    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
                );

                for ($ci = 0, $cc = count($conditions); $ci < $cc; $ci++)
                {
                    if (($op = $this->_get_operator($conditions[$ci])) === FALSE
                        OR ! preg_match('/^(\(?)(.*)('.preg_quote($op, '/').')\s*(.*(?<!\)))?(\)?)$/i', $conditions[$ci], $matches))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // $matches = array(
                    //  0 => '(test <= foo)',   /* the whole thing */
                    //  1 => '(',       /* optional */
                    //  2 => 'test',        /* the field name */
                    //  3 => ' <= ',        /* $op */
                    //  4 => 'foo',     /* optional, if $op is e.g. 'IS NULL' */
                    //  5 => ')'        /* optional */
                    // );

                    if ( ! empty($matches[4]))
                    {
                        $this->_is_literal($matches[4]) OR $matches[4] = $this->protect_identifiers(trim($matches[4]));
                        $matches[4] = ' '.$matches[4];
                    }
                    // temporal fix (has already been fixed in 3.0.1)
                    if($matches[2] == 'NOT'){
                        continue;
                    }

                    $conditions[$ci] = $matches[1].$this->protect_identifiers(trim($matches[2]))
                        .' '.trim($matches[3]).$matches[4].$matches[5];
                }

                $this->{$qb_key}[$i] = implode('', $conditions);
            }

            return ($qb_key === 'qb_having' ? "\nHAVING " : "\nWHERE ")
                .implode("\n", $this->$qb_key);
        }

        return '';
    }
```

**NOTE:** Better to update to 3.0.1 unless you have a very specific reason to not update.